# Maven / Java, what does IllegalStateException refer to?

Tags: java, exception, maven

I've been trying to run a Maven / Java application that should connect to an external server and start a visual tool.
I've tried to compile and run the code but I always have been reading the same error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java
(default-cli) on project seco-mart-registration-tool: An exception occured while 
executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Cannot deserialize base type 
java.util.List<class org.seco.mart.model.interfaces.ServiceInterface> from C:\Users\Chicco
\Desktop\BioSeCoBis\seco-mart-server\data\marts\theatre.si (format: JSON, charset: UTF-8, 
autoClose: false). IllegalStateException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) on project seco-mart-
registration-tool: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
```

I have no idea of what this IllegalStateException  could stand for.
Do you have any clue?

Thanks

Comment: See [IllegalStateException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)

Answer (score 0):

The messages states the reason for the error, you just have to ignore some of the clutter:

> Cannot deserialize base type
>   `java.util.List<class org.seco.mart.model.interfaces.ServiceInterface>`

The `InvocationTargetException` is thrown by the exec-maven-plugin which tried to run the whole thing and is caused by and uncatched `IllegalStateException`. That exception probably tries to tell you that the object just can't be deserialized in its current state.